# How hot is too hot for a laptop?

Tags: overheating

I have an MSI Gaming laptop I got not too long ago and I have a simple question for the stack...

I have a nifty application that graphically displays my system performance readout. Right now my machine is running at 36 degrees Celsius. What is the manufacturer's recommended range of operating temperature? This laptop has a special double fan feature for when it gets too hot. What temperature is a good temperature to use this?  (it must be activated manually)

Comment: What *exactly* is "running at 36 degrees Celsius"? Most modern computers have several temperature sensors.

Comment: If the processor is at 36 degrees, I would be worried about it being too cold. (Joking)

Comment: This question seems to attract opinion based answers, which is considered OffTopic here on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

Anything **below** 50 Celsius is usually a safe bet.

Anything **above** 75 Celsius for long periods of time can be unhealthy for laptops (Due to the limited space and airflow), and eventually your machine could shutdown if it exceeds the allowed temperature (Before it does damage)

**Do not rely on that though**

I would recommend kicking it on once it reaches about 50-60 Celsius.

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: *Anything above 60 Celsius for long periods of time is unhealthy for most machines* I would disagree. The 75+ Celsius range is where it's starting to become hot. 75+  Celsius is not damaging, but could shorten the longevity of the CPU. For the PC to shutdown, it would have to reach probably 90+ Celsius before it would shutdown due to being too hot.

Comment: While you are correct that 75+ is where it starts to become worrisome,  bear in mind that he is working with a Laptop.  A lot of parts are close together and his airflow is limited.  While it is not an exact science, I think its definitely something to consider.

I could probably clarify that in my answer though instead of stating _"Most machines"_

Comment: I'd also disagree on that it would be a concerning temp for a laptop. Laptops tend to run much warmer than desktops, because of the small form factor and pretty weak intake fans. Only gaming laptops, like the MSI the user has, are capable of achieving the cool temps he's experiencing. Keep in mind, this is an idle temp. When gaming on the laptop I'd expect the average temp to be between 60-65C. That's what my MSI gaming laptop ran at while gaming too. I found it to be much cooler than the old Dell 14z I had that would idle at 60C and reach the lower 80 Celsius range when gaming on it.

Comment: And also bear in mind, that a laptop is designed with this small space in mind, so its true that it takes less for the laptop to become hot, it is also a fact that its components are less likely triggering heat. So they cancel eachother out, and the 75+ rule still applies.

Comment: I'll have to keep the 75 rule in the back of my mind.  As someone who always tries to keep the temperature between 50-60, I tend to avoid pushing limits.  I will alter my answer based on that rule.

Comment: @CheesusCrust as LPChip stated in a comment this type of question is partially opinion based. So in your case your rule of thumb would be 50-60, which is fine. Those temps would be pretty conservative if someone was using a stock cooler on a CPU too, or a laptop of course. You can also use a program like CPU-Z to see the Tj Max of the CPU. It's usually something like 98 Celsius.

Comment: Why not just cite an authoritative source (like manufacturer recommendations)?

Comment: I know it's an old question, but manufacturer recommendations tend to list just the max load temps (i.e. expect 65 C for i7; keep under 90 before shut-off). 

Personally I came across this question as Ubuntu and other distros don't seem to provide out-of-the-box power saving options for laptops, but tools like TLP can help reduce power dissipation of the CPU to reduce temperatures to a more tolerable 40-50 C. Hopefully this option is also of use to others that may come across this post.

Answer (score 1):

I worked for Dell, and CPUs max heat was 105°C from factory, it never could reach it (w/o proper cooling system).

In a mounted and cooled notebook, 60°C was the maximum accepted (reach this point the notebook was marked as with some issue). The ideal was:

~40°C for normal use;

~50°C with GPU + power AC + games like BF4 (but we recomend external cooler sources before reach 50°C, to avoid peaks of heat and MB risk of burn)

Computers pieces are susceptible to environment heat, so the best is not abuse with temperature - if with low process it pass to +50°C something is wrong. If just forcing with games, a cooling source is recommended.